# Java: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException for "edgeList.next"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I know this question is answered all over the internet, especially here on StackOverflow, but I think I need a more specific answer for my case.

```
undirectedEdge temp = edgeList.next;
```

The line above is getting me this error for some reason. The "next" must be null, or something? Here is the top of my undirectedEdge class:

```
public class undirectedEdge {
public int Ni;
public int Nj;
public int edgeCost;
public undirectedEdge next;

public undirectedEdge(int i, int j, int cost) {
    Ni = i;
    Nj = j;
    edgeCost = cost;
    next = null;
}

public undirectedEdge getNext() { return next; } . . . }
```

I hope I supplied enough info. Please let me know if I should include some other code. TIA!

Comment: Class names should begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: If that line is throwing the exception, it's because `edgeList` is null.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: What does that mean? You don't know how to set a variable? How to check if a variable is null?

Comment: I am having a hard time tracing the issue. That's all.

Comment: You haven't given us any code that actually produces said exception. Either way, you have to learn to debug your own code. See [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips.

Comment: I've had plenty of practice debugging code. I am just having an issue with this particular code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159538/discussion-between-shmob-and-shmosel).